# Are readonly static strings in C# represented by integers?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string

I have few string in a class which I am using as constants.

For example

```
public class GameConstants {

    public static readonly string TERRAIN_TAG = "Terrain";
    public static readonly string COIN_TAG = "Coin";
}
```

then when I try to create an array of these strings, it gives me an error.

```
string [] _powerUpTags = new string[GameConstants.COIN_TAG];
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to`int'

Why is this so?

Comment: can you post the code where you are trying to create the array? I assume you have declared the array as int array.

Comment: Well the reason for the exception is rather simple. The GameConstants.COIN_TAG is a string and you are using it as an index for the array...

Comment: @MrLister did that just now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you should use a collection initializer

```
string [] _powerUpTags = new string[]{GameConstants.COIN_TAG};
```

`x` in `new string[x]` represents the number of elements in the array

Comment: my bad, that was simple, mixing the pythonic syntax with c# :(

Answer (score 0):

Here it requires no. of elements as Number/integer not a string

```
string [] _powerUpTags = new string[0];
```

try like this

```
string [] _powerUpTags = new string[]{GameConstants.COIN_TAG};
```